# What is the difference between space-like four-momentum and time-like four-momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor, definition, causality

I was reading a wiki page on Tachyon, came across these terms? What i need is bit of a mathematical description to understand these terms?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to learn the consequences of measuring space/time-like momentum or the definition of those?

Comment: Can you give us some idea where you are starting from? Do you know what the norm of a four vector is and how to compute it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ which defines your metric at any point in spacetime. Let's furthermore assume (only for simplicity; this is not necessary), that this spacetime is completely flat, so $g_{\mu\nu}$ becomes the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ which I choose to be

\begin{align}
\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

This is either plus or minus $\eta$, depending on the convention you are using.

Now let's say you stand in point $A = (a^0, a^1, a^2, a^3)$ in spacetime. You may ask yourself which points in spacetime can be hit by a ray of light from there. These are all the points $X = (x^0, x^1, x^2, x^4)$ which satisfy:

\begin{align}
(x^0-a^0)^2 = (x^1-a^1)^2 + (x^2-a^2)^2 + (x^3-a^3)^2
\end{align}

If we call $\Delta x^i = x^i-a^i$ and use our metric $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ we can write:

\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu=0}^3\sum_{\nu=0}^3 \eta_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^{\mu}\Delta x^{\nu} = 0
\end{align}

Using Einstein's sum convention, this gets even shorter:

\begin{align}
\eta_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^{\mu}\Delta x^{\nu} = 0
\end{align}

because we always sum over greek indices from 0 to 3. What we have now is the definition for a lighlike vector $X$, which lies directly on the so called light cone.

There are two more possibilities:

\begin{align}
&\eta_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^{\mu}\Delta x^{\nu} < 0\\
&\quad\text{and}\\
&\eta_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^{\mu}\Delta x^{\nu} > 0
\end{align}

**The first equation** describes every vector *inside* the light cone.

Now we will understand this with velocity vectors. I will call it $\dot{x}^{\mu} = (\dot{x}^0, \dot{x}^1, \dot{x}^2, \dot{x}^3)$. Since $x^0 = ct$, we get $\dot{x}^0 = c$ with $c$ being the speed of light in a vacuum. Furthermore we can for simplicity assume, that $A = (0,0,0,0)$, so the equation becomes:

\begin{align}
(\dot{x}^1)^2 + (\dot{x}^2)^2 + (\dot{x}^3)^2 &< c^2\\
\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{(\dot{x}^1)^2 + (\dot{x}^2)^2 + (\dot{x}^3)^2} &< c
\end{align}

So the magnitude of the space velocity has to be smaller than the speed of light. This is called a *timelike vector*.

**The second equation** describes every vector *outside* the light cone. Using the same argumentation as above, we get:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{(\dot{x}^1)^2 + (\dot{x}^2)^2 + (\dot{x}^3)^2} > c
\end{align}

We call vectors, that satisfy this condition *spacelike*. An object with a spacelike velocity would move faster than light.

Momentum $p$ is velocity times mass, so $p^\mu = m\dot{x}^\mu$.